# Непонятное поведение grep

Tags: linux, grep

```
grep -q "x*" <<<"zoo"
echo $?
grep -q "z*" <<<"zoo"
echo $?
```

Почему обе команды возвращают `0`? Ожидается, что в первой возвратится не 0, т.к. `zoo` не содержит `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ну так а почему ему и не срабатывать ?

`x*` - означает что x должен встречатся 0 или больше раз, а в слове `zoo` буква `x` встречается 0 раз, значит всё верно.

Возможно вы имели в виду то что **обязательно** должна присутствовать буква `x` а после неё 0 или больше символов, тогда это запишется так:

```
$ grep 'x.*' <<<"zoo";echo $?
1
```

Comment: Тогда уж просто `grep x` наверное?

Comment: @andreymal
ну, может и так, а лучше пусть автор вопроса сам определится с условием поиска

Comment: Здесь получается `*` как в регулярных выражениях? Как сделать, чтобы было как в wildcard? Где `x*` означает `x` + любое количество символов

Comment: @eristor 
да, по умолчанию условие воспринимается как регулярное выражение. Без понятия что за wildcard. Попробуйте использовать ключ `-F, --fixed-strings Interpret PATTERNS as fixed strings, not regular expressions. `

Comment: @eristor мне лень разбираться в синтаксисе грепа, но методом научного тыка `x..*` вроде работает как надо